# Defining receive method for Akka actor

Tags: akka, actor

From the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html):

> Actors are implemented by extending the `Actor` base trait and implementing the `receive` method. The `receive` method should define a series of case statements (which has the type `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`) that defines which messages your Actor can handle, using standard Scala pattern matching, along with the implementation of how the messages should be processed.

Code:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  def receive = {
    case "test" ⇒ log.info("received test")
    case _      ⇒ log.info("received unknown message")
  }
}
```

There is no input to receive, so what is being matched in the case statements?
Also, how does `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` come into the picture here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actors are message-driven and `input` is fed to an actor like messages sent to a [mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actors.html#mailbox).  Messages are most commonly [sent to an actor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala#send-messages) via the fire-and-forget `tell` (i.e. `!`), like:

```
myActor ! "test"
```

The `receive` method in an actor allows one to pattern-match the messages (generally by type) to process them accordingly.  The method has type `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` so that:

1. `case` pattern-matching, which is a partial function, fits well as a screening tool to effectively handle various types of incoming messages
2. it can take messages of any type, process them in any way necessary and doesn't need to return anything, like:

   ```
   case i: Int => // do something with i
   case s: String => // do something with s
   // ...
   ```

Note that in the case of [unhandled messages](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#defining-an-actor-class), under the hood an `UnhandledMessage()` will be published to the ActorSystem.

Answer (score 0):

The message passed to the actor is matched
eg: if `actor ! "message"` is called, then `"message"` is matched.

see here

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-communicate-send-messages-scala-akka-actors

`PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` comes into picture because because it accepts argument of `Any` type but doesn't return anything. If `"message"` is passed to the actor then `String` is the type of parameter that is passed to `PartialFunction`. During pattern match, it doesn't return a value. So `Unit` return type.